# Loading 2 Xibs, one from Xib, getting was mutated while being enumerated and wrong type

Tags: xib, nib

So, I have a plethora of problems that each have answers, but not combined.
I'm loading Xibs 2 ways. Thanks to Yang, I am using awakeAfterUsingCoder:(NSCoder*)aD {} and can get an initial load of a custom view (which has a scrollview with custom views inside it).

I then load the inner views, which use the [NSBundle]... loadNibNamed:@"Name"] objectAtIndex:0] to programmatically load from a Xib.

So far, I'm successfully loading a Xib by code, and Xib within Xib (no extra code besides AwakeAfter). Alright, good... but...

Later, when I go to add a mini-view to the scrollView, by using loadNib...options... I get this:error code... was mutated while being enumerated.

What the? So I'm apparently modifying my array, (initially I thought it was enumerating the scroll view subviews when I added, but nope... I'm not that careless). Well is it concurrency? Nope, I'm straight looping and calling delegates to say "Hey, I changed data, now add to the subviews." but that's not it, honestly... You'll love this:
Let's assume I have named my views as such.
BigScrollView (holds the inner views) and then this...
InnerView * iv;

Then I do something like this: InnerView * temp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InnerView" owner: self options: nil] objectAtIndex:0]; and even typecast it sometimes. Then, before it crashes, I decide to 
    NSLog(@"Class: %@", NSStringFromClass([temp class]));
Guess what prints? BigScrollView. Even debugging it and using PO objectName.

How does this happen?

Further searching has yielded results as to "AwakeFromNib is called every time, on every single view, that you have loaded from the Nib, as in, if you load a new nib, all your old ones also receive the call". Well, that's just weird... but later I realized that probably, and does mean that...

- (id) awakeAfterUsingCoder: is also called. Which means, when I use the InnerView's loading call, it automatically makes the BigScrollView call: awakeAfterUsingCoder:

After further inspecting this with NSLogs, I was right.

So I shoved in this line
    if(![self isKindOfClass:[BigScrollView class]]) return self;

Simply to prevent it from creating a new BigScrollView (actual type is different, just fyi, I'm really needing custom for what it is).

But that's not working.

I'm a major proponent of using Native iOS, both for its speed and ability to use Xibs custom. So don't get me wrong, I critique them without heavy feelings and often nitpick at the manuals, like how MKMapRect isn't explained unless you view WWDC 2010, or UIScrollView has "should should" in its specs, simply because I earnestly wish to understand them better and use the tools... so I say this with a light heart: How did apple make it not only possible to say "int num" and receive a float, but multithread something when not asked? Is there a general process I'm not getting?

I will likely just not instantiate the Xib with a xib and call both through code, just placing it manually, and see if that works. But I'm open to any answers, as I have not found this compound of a question on SO.

Comment: I have just reworked my code to not use awakeAfterCoder, and it works. I had a lot of extra "doLayout" stuff, but nothing using concurrency. It also never broke, but if I simply put in InnerView * iv = ...loadNibNamed:@"InnerView"] and didn't even add it, it'd still crash

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I just observed this weird behavior. In my case I was defining a custom NSCell which is loaded automatically by an NSTableView inside my main xib.  The custom cell loads another xib containing a view.  I had just put in a 2 second delay on the second load - and have been watching it get called again, and again, and again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awakeFromNib is called once for every view in the active window, for every view that gets instantiated. In other words, use a static variable to prevent 2 calls. Even then, writing my own initialization code worked better than Apple's premade solutions.

Also note, usually this works, shove initialization into this function when you know it will only be called once per view:
- (void) didMoveToSuperview {} or Window func